# Datastore Issue in Google App Engine making the application not allowing the inputs to work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

App engine application is deployed in server and is connected to the database. All the data is loaded in the list and it is showing properly, but if we give some inputs in input box or any other form fields it is not reflecting in the application. The error i got from the console of app engine was this

> `com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException`: The
>   request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large

In the App engine server I cleared the data store entries but it didn't work out well. I disabled the write access of the data store file but for few minutes it worked i was able to give the inputs and it was reflecting but after sometime the URL was not working and then I enabled the write access then the application was accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This error message was caused due the [Datastore default limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits#limits), most likely the limit related to the limit size for a Datastore entity, since the exception is thrown by `datastore_v3.Put()`:

> - Maximum size for an entity:         **1,048,572 bytes** (1 MiB - 4 bytes)

However, also take in mind the limits regarding other Datastore metrics, in the linked documentation.

I would recommend you to double check that the size of the entities you are trying to insert into Datastore falls under this value, as well as under the values of the rest of the limits.